# Python httplib, urllib syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to run the simplest python script to perform a http request and print the response:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print f.read(100)
```

And I tried many variation of this "hello http" including httplib, urllib(2), HTTPConnection and treating connection as a file descriptor. But I always end up with error code similar to this:

```
./script.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./script.py: line 2: `f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')'
```

I can't figure this out. Tried to search on web, but "syntaxe error near ..." isn't just enough to get proper answer.

Comment: Try running it directly with Python: `python myscript.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of the script. And make sure that you erase the `urllib2` file that ImageMagick has created.